# Get markup from, or include, overridden template

Tags: magento2

Does Magento 2 have a way to get an overridden template that a custom phtml file overrides? I need to make a tiny adjustment to a phtml file, and don't want to duplicate all the code and markup for the original template, just to make the small change.

A contrived example, within the custom template:

```
<?php

// Returns the processed output from the overridden template
$parentMarkup = $block->getOverriddenTemplateOutput();

?>

<div class="foo-bar">
    <?= str_replace('Foo', 'Bar', $parentMarkup) ?>
</div>
```

Or another possible way, via requiring in the overridden template directly:

```
<div class="foo-bar">
    <?php
    ob_start();
    // Returns the path of the overridden template
    require $block->getOverriddenTemplatePath();
    echo str_replace('Foo', 'Bar', ob_get_clean());
    ?>
</div>
```

The main reasons for wanting to do this are:

- Better upgrade experience. If the overridden template file has markup changes, you don't need to sync those with the custom template.
- Maintain Magento's template overriding functionality, without having to specifically `require` in the original template's path.
- DRY templates. My custom template only needs to make a small change, so why should I have to duplicate the original markup?

Thanks